# Basic C++ Code with error code: multiple definition of `main'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;

    while (val <= 10)
        sum += val;   {
        ++val;
    }
    cout << "Sum out of 1 to 10 inclusive " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is not a problem with other files in my project.

Comment: What do you mean by "other files in your project"? Do you have a self-contained program in each file in your project? Your project can only have *one* `main` function (in all of its files).

Comment: There are no other files in this project is what i meant. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Could you please put the exact error message you got?

Comment: When i debug this is what I get:21:45:07 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project aaaaa ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o a.o "..\\a.cpp" 
g++ -o aaaaa.exe a.o

Comment: Unrelated, but it looks like you have the opening brace for the `while` statement in the wrong place. It should be before `sum += val;`

Comment: When i try to run this is what I get:   g++ -o First.exe program1.o number.o newnew.o 
number.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\alexk\workspace\First\Debug/../number.cpp:6: multiple definition of `main'
program1.o:C:\Users\alexk\workspace\First\Debug/../program1.cpp:5: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ok so you have number1.cpp, program1.cpp, and a.cpp? Which file is in your comment? Can you show the contents of the rest?

Comment: Thank you it was totally related that the { was in the wrong place. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution:

Just include `sum += val;` inside the while loop..!

Should be something like below and this will work fine.

```
while (val <= 10){
    sum += val;
    ++val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple error in your code.

```
while (val <= 10)
    sum += val;   {
    ++val;
}
```

If you look closely you will see that only

```
sum += val;
```

is inside your while loop and val does not change due to which it becomes an infinite loop

You should change your code to

```
while (val <= 10)
  {
    sum += val;   
    ++val;
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@trash i have done a slight modification in code and ran it in https://ideone.com/RCwp6c

the edit is at

```
while (val <= 10)
        sum += val;{   
        ++val;
    }
```

change is at the curve bracket

```
while (val <= 10){ 
            sum += val;  
            ++val;
        }
```

Run your original code now..it is edited

Comment: @Trash i am happy to know it was helpful :)